# Mock CompletableFuture in spock

Tags: java, spock

i trying create stub or mock for CompletableFuture in spock. My method is called async and return CompletableFuture.  In spock method always return null. What's wrong?

```
public class  ProductFactory() {

    @Autowired
    ProductRepository repository;

    public Product create(String name) { 
        this.checkProductExists(name);
    }


    public CompletableFuture<Boolean> checkProductExists(String name) {
        //call repository and return 
        boolean  result = this.repository.checkProductExists(name);

        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(result)
    }
}





class ProductFactorySpec extends Specification {


    ProductRepository repository = Mock(ProductRepository)


    ProductFactory factory = new ProductFactory(repository)

    def "When i decide create new product"() {

        def future = CompletableFuture.completedFuture(true)

        when:

        repository.checkProductExists("Fake string") >> future

        future.get() >> true

        def result = this.factory.create(fakeOfferData())
        then:
        result instanceof Product
    }
}
```

Update code, it's was not completed.

Comment: Why not include your code in the question so it's more easy for us to see what is going on

Comment: `
public void create(String name) { 
    this.checkProductExists(name);
}


public CompletableFuture<Boolean> checkProductExists(String name) {
    //imeplementation 

    
}`

Something like this.

Comment: Please edit your question with the full code.

Comment: Where and how are you creating the mock, and where do you configure it please provide the whole code?

Comment: sorry, now should be fine

Answer (score 0):

- `items.checkProductExists("Fake string") >> future`: items is not defined, did you mean `factory`?
- `boolean  result = this.repository.checkProductExists(name);` this line doesn't expect a future, so why are you trying to return one
- `future.get() >> true` you created a real `CompletableFuture` so stubbing is not possible
- All stubbing should be performed outside of the `when` block in the `given`/`setup` block
- Your `create` doesn't return a `Product`

From the code you have provided:

```
class ProductFactorySpec extends Specification {


    ProductRepository repository = Stub()


    ProductFactory factory = new ProductFactory(repository)

    def "When i decide create new product"() {
        given:
        repository.checkProductExists(_) >> true

        when:
        def result = factory.create("fakeProduct")

        then:
        result instanceof Product
    }
}
```

Comment: @Matrix12 please provide the actual runnable code, I've given my answer as best as your code let me.

Answer (score 0):

You can force to complete the future using future.complete(true)

```html
def "When i decide create new product"() {

        def future = new CompletableFuture<Boolean>()

        when:

        repository.checkProductExists("Fake string") >> future
        future.complete(true)

        def result = this.factory.create(fakeOfferData())
        then:
        result instanceof Product
    }
```